# Angular2 reactive form's ngFor input loose focus

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular, typescript

I'm implementing 'input form' which has variable number of items depend on user's setting. Here, `timeZones` could be set by users.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(form.value)">
    <span *ngFor = "let key of timeZones | mapToIterable">
        <label>{{ key.key }}</label>
        <input formControlName="{{ key.key }}">
    </span>
</form>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Code part is like below,

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    date: [ '' ],             // Fixed date collector
});

for(var key in this.timeZones){  // variable number of objects
    this.form.addControl( key, this.fb.control(['', ]));
}
```

I can see the form input menus but **input menu's focus disappear after click is off**, interestingly, if I move input html into below *ngFor loop (manually put formControlName), the focus works well. I can put some value with the other hand while I'm clicking on the input menu, and submit button shows result correctly. Could you help me to find the solution?

Comment: I corrected this issue with using array. It seems to be related with the pipe `mapToIterable` to get the object `timeZones`'s key value. I just created an array which has keys and used it